# Can i open Terminal in MAC using selenium Webdriver?

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, terminal

I am using MAC. Is there any way I can open **Terminal** using selenium web driver and post some commands?

Answer (score 1):

No. The Selenium WebDriver is for automating a *web browser* -- it's not a general system automation tool.

Depending on how you are running Selenium, it might be more appropriate to run a shell command directly from your test.